# Closed loops on nonconservative vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-fields, greens-theorem

Consider the following (very simple) nonconservative vector field:

$$V = (y, -x)$$

sketched in the following figure:

[image]

Roughly speaking, the integral along the central red circle is obviously $\neq 0$.

But what about the lower red circle? Intuitively I'd say it has too a nonvanishing integral...[some sources say it's so](https://kasadkad.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/de-rham-cohomology/), but [some other say it vanishes](https://www.mathphysicsbook.com/mathematics/manifolds/homology-on-manifolds/the-poincare-lemma/)...who's right?

Comment: There is a non-conservative vector field for which any integral not containing the origin vanishes. This is not that one (for instance because the vector length increases toward the origin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

$V = (y, -x) = (V_x, V_y), \tag 1$

we have

$\nabla \times V = \dfrac{\partial V_y}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial V_x}{\partial y} = -1 - 1 = -2; \tag 2$

by Stokes' theorem, the integral of $V$ over any open region $\Omega$ with $\partial \Omega = C(t)$, a simple closed curve, is given by

$\displaystyle \int_C V \cdot \vec{ds} = \int_\Omega (\nabla \times V) \; dA = \int_\Omega (-2)\; dA = -2 \cdot \text{area}(\Omega) \ne 0; \tag 3$

since the lower red circle in the figure obviously bounds a region of non-zero area, we see that

$\displaystyle \int_C V \cdot \vec{ds} \ne 0 \tag 4$

where $C$ is taken to be this circle.